# Lumix GX8: How set long shutterspeed on electronic shutter?

Tags: long-exposure, shutter-speed, panasonic-lumix

The camera allows me only 1" when electronic shutter speed is on. 
Need 24" for stars, but that's possible only in mechanical shutter mode. 
Would like to avoid shaking.
Is there any workaround ?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often electronic shutter mode is limited to shorter duration because of increased noise. That seems to be the case here. In fact, according to the manual, one second is only available at ISOs up to 3200 — at higher ISOs, it's limited to something faster than that.

There isn't a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, that seems logical